# Как сделать image в форме круга?

Tags: unity3d

Хочу узнать могу ли я сделать image в форме круга?
Нужно сделать не просто спрайт в форме круга а и площадь самого image.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а зачем Вам это?

Comment: если вам это нужно для того, что бы райкаст происходил именно только на самой картинке, не затрагивая пустую часть блока компонента - то можете попробовать ограничить область с помощью маски - Mask или Rect Mask 2d компонент

Comment: @animagnoa мб круглый коллайдер?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ имхо лучше сделать маской, юзать методы специальные для UI и не впутывать физику если она в принципе там не нужна

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя. Т.к. форму квадрата имеет не `Image`, а объект интерфейса, на котором он висит.

`Image` - это компонент, который умеет рисовать спрайты.
`GameObject` - это игровой объект, на который вы можете повесить компоненты.

Каждый `GameObject` обладает компонентом `Transform`, который задаёт им физические параметры - такие как позиция в мире, скейл и поворот.

`GameObject` созданные внутри `Canvas` обладают наследником `Transform` - `RectTransform`, который прибавляет к ранее названным характеристикам ещё Anchor (интерфейсный якорь) и ширину/высоту.

Квадратную форму ваш объект с компонентом `Image` имеет именно благодаря `RectTransform`. Он будет иметь её даже, если `Image` вы удалите, т.к. это свойство именно самого объекта и `Image` его только использует для отрисовки спрайта.